# params.getValue() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, mern

I am trying to acess the value of the row's column id so that when one click on the icon it will change the url followed by the id but there is an error that TypeError: params.getValue is not a function. I have tried changing it but cannot fnd the alternate or updated version of this. So if you can help me it will be a great help.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/d804b.png)

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import "./MyOrders.css";
import { userSelector, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { clearErrors, myOrders } from "../../actions/orderAction";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader";
import { Link, useFormAction, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";
import LaunchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Launch";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const MyOrders = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();
  const { loading, error, orders } = useSelector((state) => state.myOrders);
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "Order Id", minwidth: 300, flex: 1 },
    {
      field: "status",
      headerName: "Status",
      minwidth: 150,
      flex: 0.5,
    },

    {
      field: "itemsQty",
      headerName: "Items Qty",
      type: "number",
      minwidth: 150,
      flex: 0.3,
    },
    {
      field: "amount",
      headerName: "Amount",
      type: "number",
      minwidth: 270,
      flex: 0.5,
    },
    {
      field: "actions",
      flex: 0.3,
      headerName: "Actions",
      minwidth: 150,
      type: "number",
      sortable: false,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <Link to={`/order/${params.getValue(params.id, "id")}`}>
            <LaunchIcon />
          </Link>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
  const rows = [];

  orders &&
    orders.forEach((item, index) => {
      rows.push({
        itemsQty: item.orderItems.length,
        id: item._id,
        status: item.orderStatus,
        amount: item.totalPrice,
      });
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
    dispatch(myOrders());
  }, [dispatch, error, alert]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MetaData title={`${user.name} - Orders`} />
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <div className="myOrdersPage">
          <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={10}
            disableSelectionOnClick
            className="myOrdersTable"
            autoHeight
          />
          <Typography id="myOrdersHeading">{user.name}'s Orders</Typography>
        </div>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default MyOrders;
```

Comment: which version of the library are you using?

Comment: "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.16.3",

Answer (score 0):

Okay, according to documentation, a proper way to access a value of a cell for the particular row and field would be to use:

```js
    renderCell: (params) => {
      params.api.getCellValue(rowId, field)
      ...
    },
```

However you are not trying to access another row, but current row so it could be simplified to:

```js
    renderCell: (params) => {
      params.row[field]
      ...
    },
```

Moreover you are not just trying to access any field, you are trying to access id specifically, which also has its custom getter:

```js
    renderCell: (params) => {
      params.id
      ...
    },
```

So in short you could replace your function with just

```js
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return (
        <Link to={`/order/${params.id}`}>
          <LaunchIcon />
        </Link>
      )
    },
```